# Spring Data JPA - NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem when consulting the database in my RestAPI made with SpringBoot - Spring Data JPA.

When I try to get one credential by its IdUserFK only works when there is ONLY ONE user. If there is more than one credential querying by the IdUferFK the server, I get the following error:

> javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2

I've read that the problem is that uniqueResult is true in hibernate but I don't know how to set it to false to return more than one credential if needed

MySQL database

```
CREATE DATABASE credentialManager CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE credentialManager;

CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id_user INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_user VARCHAR(256),
    password_user VARCHAR(256)
);
    
CREATE TABLE credentials 
(
    id_credential INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_credential VARCHAR(256),
    user_credential VARCHAR(256),
    password_credential VARCHAR(256),
    id_user_fk INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user_fk)
        REFERENCES users (id_user)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Interface ICredentialDAO

```
public interface ICredentialDAO extends CrudRepository<Credential, Long> {

    Credential findAllByIdUserFK(Long idUserFK);
}
```

Interface ICredentialService

```
public interface ICredentialService {

    List<Credential> findAll();

    List<Credential> findAllByIdUserFK(Long id);
}
```

Class CredentialServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class CredentialServiceImpl implements ICredentialService {

    @Autowired
    private ICredentialDAO credentialDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Credential> findAll() {
        return (List<Credential>) credentialDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Credential> findAllByIdUserFK(Long id) {
        return (List<Credential>) credentialDAO.findAllByIdUserFK(id);
    }
}
```

Controller CredentialRestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CredentialRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ICredentialService credentialService;

    @GetMapping("/credentials")
    public List<Credential> index() {
        return credentialService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/credentials/user/{idUser}")
    public List<Credential> showCredential(@PathVariable Long idUser) {
        return this.credentialService.findAllByIdUserFK(idUser);
    }
}
```

The full error when I try to do a get to *localhost:8080/api/credentials/user/1* in Postman is this

```
"timestamp": "2021-04-30T11:53:56.691+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:385)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.findAllByIdUserFK(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.fortun.credmanback.models.services.CredentialServiceImpl.findAllByIdUserFK(CredentialServiceImpl.java:38)\r\n\tat com.fortun.credmanback.models.services.CredentialServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cd2fa77a.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)\r\n\tat com.fortun.credmanback.models.services.CredentialServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e44cbb0.findAllByIdUserFK(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.fortun.credmanback.controllers.CredentialRestController.showCredential(CredentialRestController.java:31)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)\r\nCaused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1648)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryQueryMethodInvoker$$Lambda$1086/0x0000000000000000.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 71 more\r\n",
    "message": "query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2",
    "path": "/api/credentials/user/1"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

```
List<Credential> findAllByIdUserFK(Long idUserFK);
```

instead of

```
Credential findAllByIdUserFK(Long idUserFK);
```

in your `ICredentialDAO`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some constraints (like @Unique field) in your model that there should be a single entity for a single id. But somehow db has 2 rows for this same id. That's why it causes an error when mapping the results.

Comment: Im not creating the DB in Data JPA so @Unique don't apply here. 
In my database I have two rows with the same foreign key, what its pretty common so I dont understand why I cant find by that foreign key.

Comment: Is there any constraint for the foreign key in the db level?

Comment: I've updated the post with the database code at the top so you can see it.